# OLS regression data eviews

Tags: linear-regression, eviews

I'm doing an OLS regression to estimate the global financial cycle from 1980q2 to 2018q4.
I have to use all dependent variables in growth rate but when I use GDP in growth rate I get non-significant results whereas if I use it in levels I get a significant result.

These are the data I'm using in the first case:
[image: gdp growth rate]
And I have this output:
[image: first case output]

Instead these are the data I'm using in the second case:
[image: data with gdp in level]
And this is the output:
[image: second case output]

The regression I'm doing using Eviewsis:
gfc=C(1)+C(2)*ggrowth(-1)+C(3)*inflation(-1)+C(4)*gdp(-1)+C(5)*spread10y2y(-1)+C(6)*policyrate(-1)+C(7)*gfc(-1)

All dependent variables are lagged by one period

I'm taking the data from

inflation USA: `https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/CORESTICKM159SFRBATL#0`

policy rate USA: `https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DFF#0`

spread 10y2y USA: `https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/T10Y2Y#0`

gdp USA: `https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/GDPC1#0`

g usa: (`https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/W068RCQ027SBEA`)

Can you help me understanding if the regression I've done is correct? Or can you help me doing the right regression to have a significant result?
Thank you very much.